# Secure data sent from AJAX Post

Tags: php, ajax, security

I'm thinking about how to secure form data that's sent from an AJAX post submittal.  Ie. if user wants to secure text and files that will be mailed to someone.

So, to generalize, I see three steps in delivery.

1- From browser to my server (& then php process)

2- From my server, email is encrypted using php & sent out to final destination

3- Email is received and then decrypted using php

So step 1 is what I'm focusing on at the moment.  What method could I use that would scramble the data, in case it's intercepted by a man-in-the middle attack before it reaches my server?  Obviously, everything on page can be seen, so how do I ensure security?  A good explanation & examples would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

install ssl on the server and use https

Comment: Ok, so what if you can't install ssl, i.e. 3rd party server that you have no control over?

Comment: Then you are, in a word, hose @parti

Comment: In that case you can do.. 1.nada 2.zilch 3.nothing

Comment: He could find a different host @Tom ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm curious how he found a host that doesn't support SSL.  Is it 1995 again??